# Why cannot I access admin section of redirects app in Django?

Tags: django, redirect, admin

I have recently installed the redirects app provided by Django (docs:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/redirects/)

I went through the proper steps to install it: added to installed apps, added to end of Middleware, and migrated my database. See below:
'django.contrib.redirects',
'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',

The table successfully was created. However, I cannot seem to view /admin/redirects/redirect. I'm getting the following error

Exception Value:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'redirect'
```

I manually added a record to the django_redirect table and the redirect works. Any ideas why I cannot access the redirects app via the admin?

Edit: The admin URLs are at the top of my urls.py however, it appears it is not matching the pattern and its hitting a URL pattern below it. Thoughts?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart Gunicorn

```
sudo systemctl stop gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
```

Then you should see tables in Django administration